# VSCode .NET Core Console - how to point startup to SomeOtherProgram.cs?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I have a .NET Core Console app. From VSCode, how to point startup to SomeOtherProgram.cs? (Default is Program.cs)

I can imagine I can tweek launch.json?

Thanks

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: .NET Core Console dont have startup.cs

Answer (score 1):

When build, your project will search for `Main` method from all over your codes. One project can only have one `Main` method, or it will cause an error.
[image]
So you could create another "test.cs" as new entry point just add a `Main` method inside. For the original `program.cs`, just change the `Main` method name to something else, such as `Main_disabled(string[] args)` to stop this entry point.